# error "name 'new_local_repository' is not defined" in bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I understand that the following load is required for `new_git_repository`:
`load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository", "new_git_repository")`

But how do I find the load required for `new_local_repository`. I tried browsing the [build_defs git folder](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/tools/build_defs/repo) but `new_local_repository` is not defined there so I could not guess the load.

I get the the following error - `name 'new_local_repository' is not defined`. How do I find the required load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're calling `new_local_repository` inside a `.bzl` file that's loaded from the `WORKSPACE` file, you have to use `native.new_local_repository` instead. This is because `new_local_repository` is defined in Bazel core and not any `.bzl` file.

Comment: but if i try "native.new_local_repository" , it show error : "name 'native' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using `new_local_repository` inside a function in a `.bzl` file I was loading in WORKSPACE and then calling the function. Moving `new_local_repository` rule to the WORKSPACE file fixed the issue for me.